# How I can automate this R Code, with parameters?

Tags: r, parameters

```
YR = "2021"
```

Then my result should:

```
levels = c("202101", "202102", "202103", "202104", "202105", "202106", "202107", "202108", "202109", "202110", "202111", "202112"),

labels = c("Jan-2021", "Feb-2021", "Mar-2021", "Apr-2021","May-2021","Jun-2021","Jul-2021","Aug-2021","Sep-2021","Oct-2021","Nov-2021","Dec-2021"))
```

This is created for labels.

If I change it to

```
YR = 2022
```

Then my result should:

```
levels: c("202201","202202",...,"202212"), 
labels = c("Jan-2022", "Feb-2022",...,"Dec-2022"))
```

Comment: A bit of a tweak to previous answers like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812493/how-to-add-leading-zeros or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40658189/create-sequence-of-numbers-with-leading-zeroes should do it. E.g.: `sprintf('%d%02d', 2021, 1:12)`

Comment: I don't understand your intended result. Is that a `data.frame` with 2 columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. the first target can refer the link in the comment.
2. `month.abb` function can provide the abbreviation of each month.

```r
YR = "2021"
levels <- sprintf('%s%02d', YR, 1:12)
levels
#>  [1] "202101" "202102" "202103" "202104" "202105" "202106" "202107" "202108"
#>  [9] "202109" "202110" "202111" "202112"
labels <- paste0(month.abb,"-",YR)
# or
# labels <- sprintf('%s%s%s',month.abb,"-",YR)
labels
#>  [1] "Jan-2021" "Feb-2021" "Mar-2021" "Apr-2021" "May-2021" "Jun-2021"
#>  [7] "Jul-2021" "Aug-2021" "Sep-2021" "Oct-2021" "Nov-2021" "Dec-2021"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your notification.  But  sometimes code itself with necessary comment is enough for some specific question. Not each simple code needed to be explained.  If I think it's hard to understand, I will explain it without hesitation.